# Curl filename upload using variable

Tags: bash, curl

I would like to store the pathname of a file in a variable for that gets uploaded via cURL. The problem is that I must not have the syntax correct.

```
curl --user-agent Mozilla -v --form filename=@/path/to/filename -F .submit=Upload http://example.com/upload.cgi
```

^ the above works just fine, however i would like to store the path in a variable, so when i try:

```
var=$(pwd)/filename;

curl --user-agent Mozilla -v --form filename=@$var -F .submit=Upload http://example.com/upload.cgi
```

it comes back as malformed, or the path is missing altogether.

Comment: what OS are you using? Because the example you gave works just fine for me on Mac OS X.

Comment: @ksimons - hi, i'm on OS X. and which example worked, the first or the second? the first is fine. the second doesn't though for me.

Comment: The second worked for me as well. Are you sure the file pointed at by $var actually exists?

Comment: yes, i can echo the var and it reads /harddrive/file

Comment: But does /harddrive/file exist? It needs to

Comment: Why `$(pwd)` instead of `$PWD`?